# I have to compare two large dataframes, how can I do it using multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

One row in one dataframe should be compared with all other rows in other dataframe and should print column names that are equal in each row in second dataframe.
eg:

```
a=[['apple','cotton','pineapple']]
b=[['apple','lemon','pineapple'],['apple','cotton','mango'],['grapes','cotton','pineapple']]
```

consider **a** is a dataframe with one row 3 columns,and **b** is a dataframe with 3 rows and 3 columns:
My output while comparing first row of a with b should be:

```
0 2
0 1
1 2
```

0 is name if first column, 1 is name of second column,2 is name of third column.
Actual problem has million rows.So how can I do it using multiprocessing.

Comment: Could you please provide a mininal attempt to solve the problem? Please provide code so that others can reproduce your example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Mulitprocessing is just one powerful tool to speed up computing intensive tasks. Here the first question if whether all can fit in memory, both input dataframes and the result. If the answer is yes, then split the larger dataframe in chunks, and start one Python script for each chunk.